# ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException on upsert

Tags: nullpointerexception, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch v. 1.4.1 ("lucene_version": "4.10.2")

I have a document like this:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:9200/blog/article/1'
{
 "_index":"blog",
 "_type":"article",
 "_id":"1",
 "_version":4,
 "found":true,
 "_source":{
    "id":"1",
    "title":"First Elasticsearch doc!",
    "testfield":"abcd"
 }
}
```

I was just trying the upsert example here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts

```
$ curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/blog/article/1/_update' -d '{
>     "script" : "ctx._source.counter += count",
>     "params" : {
>         "count" : 4
>     },
>     "upsert" : {
>         "counter" : 1
>     }
> }'
```

and I am getting this error:

```
{"error":"ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; 
  nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[NullPointerException[Cannot execute null+null]]; ",
 "status":400}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That section in the documentation states the following:

> There is also support for upsert. If the document does not already exists, the content of the upsert element will be used to index the fresh doc:

From that I understand that that example is for a document that doesn't exist. If it doesn't then the new document will contain `counter` field with value `1`. In your case, you already have a document which doesn't contain `counter`. And this is a problem, as the new field will not be added to it, that's just for non-existent documents.

In your case, you either need to have `counter` field in the already existent document or do something like this:

```
POST /blog/article/1/_update
{
  "script": "if (!ctx._source.counter) {ctx._source.counter = 1};ctx._source.counter += count",
  "params": {
    "count": 4
  }
}
```

meaning, in your script add the new `counter` field and initialize it with `1` and then do the increment.